# How many user stores when there are multiple user account types?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity

Is there a best practice for the storage of users in Azure AD B2C with different account types where the same user might be in multiple groups?

For example, let's say that we have the following user account types.

**User Account Types**

- **Member**: User that can view their health insurance information.
- **Group Leader**: User that manages a company's health benefits and members.

Of those two types, a member can also be a group leader, and a group leader can also be a member, but they don't have to be. Both account types are managed by a single company.

**Recommended Identity Architecture?**

Give those account types, how many instances of B2C should there be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be in the same directory. Just user the group membership or role attribute for authorization in the application.

Comment: An answer to a similar question from someone else on an Auth0 forum said the same thing. I also tend to agree with you, Jas. Reference to other post: https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-handle-different-user-types/30537/4